# JavaScript keycode allow number and plus symbol only

Tags: javascript, keycode

I have this JavaScript function that is used to force user only type number in the textbox. Right now and I want to modify this function so it will allow the user to enter plus (+) symbol. How to achieve this?

```
//To only enable digit in the user input

function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Greetings cyberfly All answers are fine but be warned QC will return an issue to you that if you implement this function they will tell you i cant copy and paste in this textbox or even cut & paste or even select all so also you have to enable the user to use the following keys
Ctrl + A ,
Ctrl + C ,
Ctrl + V ,
Ctrl + A

Comment: Don't use charcode, use a regular expression and the value. Preventing input really annoys users, let them enter whatever and validate on submit. What about pasting from the context or Edit menus?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the '+' symbol's decimal ASCII code is 43, you can add it to your condition.

for example :

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode != 43 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

This way, the Plus symbol is allowed.

Comment: thanks it simple and works. i have tried something like your solution before but the char code i am referring is 107. http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

Answer (score 7):

This code might work. I added support for `SHIFT + (equal sign)` and the numpad `+`.

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  var shiftPressed = (window.Event) ? e.modifiers & Event.SHIFT_MASK : e.shiftKey;

  if ((shiftPressed && charCode == 187) || (charCode == 107))
  {
    return true;
  } else if ((charCode > 95) && (charCode < 106)) {
    return true;
  } else if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `(shiftPressed && charCode == 187)`. `187` is the keyCode of the `=` key, since `shift + =` = `+`. I'm a bit confused about what you're asking...

Comment: I tried this but only Plus key is working and `Shift + =` key is returning false.. also `e` is not defined in `e.modifiers` and `e.shiftKey`

Answer (score 3):

this is stupid ... not really an answer at all. I would suggest you to do following.

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    console.log(evt.keyCode);
    return false;
}
```

And find out the ranges of all keys, and implement it.

Answer (score 3):

It's Work. Javascript keycode allow number and plus symbol only

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript form validation</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" action="#">

Mobile Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text'  id='PhoneNumber' maxlength="10" onKeyPress="return IsNumeric3(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"/>
<span id="error3" style="color: Red; display: none">* Input digits (0 - 9)</span>

</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var specialKeys = new Array();
        specialKeys.push(8); 
  specialKeys.push(43); 
  specialKeys.push(37); 
  specialKeys.push(39); 
  //Backspace
        function IsNumeric3(e) {
            var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
            var ret = (keyCode != 37 && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 46 && (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
            document.getElementById("error3").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
            return ret;
        }
    </script>

 <script>
function stringlength(inputtxt, minlength, maxlength)
{ 
var field = inputtxt.value; 
var mnlen = minlength;
var mxlen = maxlength;

if(field.length<mnlen || field.length> mxlen)
{ 
alert("Please input the 10 digit mobile number");
return false;
}
else
{ 

return true;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you friends

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code:

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if ( (charCode >= 48  && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 43) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code . working fine with numbers and plus + sign in phone fields. you will have to implement the code on keydown function . target the id/class of the particular phone field and use keydown function.

```
    //allows only these keys
    // backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
    if ( event.keyCode == 107 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
         // Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
             return;
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using experience of my colleagues above, write one function, that fits me well. It filters all except numbers, arrows and backspace. Maybe it would be useful for somebody.

```
function isKeyCorrect(keyEvent) {
    var charCode = keyEvent.which ? keyEvent.which : keyEvent.keyCode;
    var isNotNumber = charCode < 48 || charCode > 57;
    var isNotArrow = charCode < 37 || charCode > 40;
    var isNotBackspace = charCode !== 8;

    return isNotNumber && isNotArrow && isNotBackspace;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    `enter code here`  $('#form-1').submit(function(msg) {  
        $.post("action.php?act=login",$(this).serialize(),function(data){      
            if (data == 'ERR:A3001004') { alert("Güvenlik hatası, sayfayı yenileyin."); }
            else if (data == 'TIMEEND') { alert("Anahtarınızın süresi dolmuş.");    }
            else if (data == 'INVALID') { alert("Geçersiz anahtar şifresi girdiniz.");  }
            else if (data == 'OK') { alert("Başarıyla giriş yaptınız. Yetişkinlere göre içerik barındıran sitelere erişim sağlayabilirsiniz."); }
        });

        return false; 
    });
});
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
</script>
```