# Trigger html5 validation without form post

Tags: html, validation

I want to achieve something like this without form post, as it will redirect the page.
[image]

here is my code

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" step="any" min="0" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter price with decimal format, eg x.xx .')">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I've did some research it seems like it has to be triggered with form post. Possible to trigger the html5 validtion with jquery function button click ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show setCustomValidity message/tooltip without submit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785347/how-to-show-setcustomvalidity-message-tooltip-without-submit-event)

Answer (score 1):

Set a custom validation message on input change and intercept the form submit event:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form'),
    input = document.querySelector('#input-price');

input.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  if (!input.checkValidity() || !/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(input.value)) {
    input.setCustomValidity("Please enter price with decimal format, eg x.xx .");
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});

form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="input-price" type="number" step="any" min="0" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

`input.checkValidity()` returns true when the input value is a number as in `2`, `.1` and `1e10`. The regex test then filters the two last cases (`.1` and `1e10`) out.

Comment: [Documentation for `checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Methods)

Answer (score 0):

#### the html5 “pattern” attribute doesn't work in all Browsers

the only way is to use JavaScript code

try this code

Html

```
<input id="amount" maxlength="7" type="text" />
```

javaScript

```
$("#amount").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,3})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        alert("Please enter price with decimal format, eg x.xx!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

#### to avoid accepting invalid input when pasting text  (idea of @le_m)

try this second solution :

html

```
<input id="amount" maxlength="7" type="text" />
```

JS

```
$("#amount").on("change paste keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d*(\.\d*)?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        alert("Please enter price with decimal format, eg x.xx!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 7);
    }
});
```

result :
http://jsfiddle.net/vY39r/866/

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390665/html-input-that-takes-only-numbers-and-the-symbol to avoid accepting invalid input when pasting text or holding a key down.

Comment: the problem of pasting text is fixed but when holding '2' for example it accept '2222222' . I test onblur and onfocusout but it doesn't solve the problem