# Restrict user to enter first two characters as Alphabets and not numbers

Tags: angular

How to achieve this I am using Angular 7 and typescript
I have a Input field data like this DK9520000123456789
So i want the user to restrict to enter the first two characters only be letters and not numbers. ("DK"9520000123456789)
I do not want the user to enter numbers in the first two characters.

```
<form class="bank-form-container {{ labelClass }}" [formGroup]="bankForm">
  <div class="col-md-6 pl-0">
    <label for="bankAcc" class="bank-label"> {{ label }}<i class="validateField">*</i> </label>
    <input
      [type]="isMaskedBankAcc ? 'password' : 'text'"
      (keypress)="numericOnly($event)"
      oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
      id="bankAcc"
      sp-popover
      name="bankAccountNumber"
      placement="right"
      placeholder="{{ placeHolder }}"
      class="form-control sp-focus text-uppercase"
      formControlName="bankAcc"
      appBlockCopyPaste
      autocomplete="off"
      (blur)="maskAndEncryptBankNumber()"
      (focus)="unmaskBankNumber()"
      [ngbTooltip]="toolTip"
      [pattern]="pattern"
      [required]="isRequired"
    />

ngOnInit() {



    this.bankForm = new FormGroup({
      bankAcc: new FormControl({ value: this.value ? this.value : '', disabled: this.isDisabled }, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^\w{2}\d+$/i),
      ]),
      bankConfirmedAcc: new FormControl({ value: this.value ? this.value : '', disabled: true }, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^\w{2}\d+$/i),
        this.checkMatchingValues.bind(this),
      ]),
    });

    this.checkFormValues();
    this.unmaskConfirmedBankNumber();
  }
```

Comment: check please this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928083/iban-validation-check

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a FormControl for that.

Then simply add pattern validator: `Validators.pattern(/^\w{2}\d+$/i)`.
It requires a user to enter 2 letters and then only numbers.

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
    inputField: new FormControl('', {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\w{2}\d+$/)],
    }),
});
```

in template

```html
<input [formControl]="form.get('inputField')">
<div *ngIf="form.get('inputField').hasError('pattern')">wrong pattern</div>
```

Comment: where should i add the pattern validatior?

Comment: THIS IS MY INPUT <input
      [type]="isMaskedBankAcc ? 'password' : 'text'"
      (keypress)="numericOnly($event)"
      oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
      id="bankAcc"
      sp-popover
      name="bankAccountNumber"
      placement="right"
      placeholder="{{ placeHolder }}"
      class="form-control sp-focus text-uppercase"
      formControlName="bankAcc"
      appBlockCopyPaste
      autocomplete="off"
      (blur)="maskAndEncryptBankNumber()"
      (focus)="unmaskBankNumber()"
     />

Comment: usually you should have a FormGroup, then the 2nd argument is the place to add validators.

Comment: <form class="bank-form-container {{ labelClass }}" [formGroup]="bankForm">
  <div class="col-md-6 pl-0">
    <label for="bankAcc" class="bank-label"> {{ label }}<i class="validateField">*</i> </label>
    <input
      [type]="isMaskedBankAcc ? 'password' : 'text'"
      (keypress)="numericOnly($event)"
      oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">

Comment: yeah, your input should be refactored. instead of `this.value = this.value` try to use `formControl`.

Comment: No need to add anything in typescript , can you add beside input and show me please

Comment: I've updated the answer. Also please check https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms - that's one of techniques how to work with inputs in Angular.

Comment: i already have this in my ts file  Validators.pattern(this.pattern) how to add this pattern in my case (/^\w{2}\d+$/)

Comment: replace `this.pattern` with `(/^\w{2}\d+$/i` or set the `pattern` property of the class to `(/^\w{2}\d+$/i`, no quotes, copy it as it is.

Comment: i am using keypress event  <input   (keypress)="numericOnly($event)" and in typescript

Comment: numericOnly(event): boolean {    
    let patt = (/^\w{2}\d+$/)
    let result = patt.test(event.key);
    return result;
} will this work

Comment: let patt = /^\w{2}\d+$/; is this correct what is w and d?

Comment: numericOnly(event): boolean {    
    let patt = /^\w{2}\d+$/;
    let result = patt.test(event.key);
    return result;
}  THIS DOES NOT WORK :(

Comment: it's hard to say what is wrong, you can post the code of the component and the template in the question for better understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure `event.key` contains the value of the input. maybe just a key of hit button.

Comment: The code you posted looks good, the fields won't be valid unless their value is DK9520000123456789

Comment: that is ok my problem is i want to prevent the user from entering numeric values at first two places  instead of "DK" user should not enter numbers

Comment: CAN YOU HELP ME WITH THIS

Comment: aaah, so you want to omit wrong input, don't you? if I typed D and then type 9 - the input still has D without 9, right?

Comment: correct that is what i needed how to do that help me

Comment: Then use the pattern from our thread and this callback: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419588/13112018